Lighthouse Exited (137
I'm running lighthouse ver v5.3.0 and geth by docker, but I don't know why lighthouse exit with code 137
some latest logs:
Nov 05 19:30:53.785 ERRO State reconstruction failed             error: MissingHistoricBlocks { oldest_block_slot: Slot(2628064) }, service: beacon
Nov 05 19:30:53.786 INFO UPnP Attempting to initialise routes
Nov 05 19:30:53.799 INFO ENR Initialised                         quic6: None, quic4: Some(9001), udp6: None, tcp6: None, tcp4: Some(9000), udp4: None, ip4: None, id: 0x93e6..4363, seq: 205, enr: enr:-La4QEUhzkEUhutS3O_jz86W64qW_K1-WqQaSI1H3DjcCFlOKv6tXqQYTYCawKj87P67___WgJxwp3qaGwHV7fQb2KKBzYdhdHRuZXRziAAAAAAAAAAAhGV0aDKQaa4OmQUBcAD__________4JpZIJ2NIRxdWljgiMpiXNlY3AyNTZrMaEC66JY4Owdh5T9X3Js-LsitQcYqPgLxuLRi64381C7GeGIc3luY25ldHMAg3RjcIIjKA, service: libp2p
Nov 05 19:31:06.000 WARN Syncing deposit contract block cache    est_blocks_remaining: initializing deposits, service: slot_notifier
Nov 05 19:31:09.578 WARN State cache missed                      state_root: 0xcc79c487b710f312d4635d23f9ceea87083a0d68a1fbb5f25ed42a3e9ff0d9f6, service: freezer_db
Nov 05 19:31:17.238 WARN State cache missed                      state_root: 0xd011e667752330066092e5a2841b17169e2b61ab494f09a440b187cfff66bb54, service: freezer_db
Nov 05 19:31:18.013 INFO Syncing                                 est_time: 1 min, speed: 2.42 slots/sec, distance: 209 slots (41 mins), peers: 8, service: slot_notifier
Nov 05 19:31:18.014 WARN Syncing deposit contract block cache    est_blocks_remaining: initializing deposits, service: slot_notifier
